# How to run robot framework test cases parallel and not Test Suite parallel?

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to run my test case from different suites in parallel using the command

```
pabot --verbose --processes 3 --variable --variable url:http://xxxxxxxxx:8080  --include Sanity --output original.xml --randomize all TestCases
```

There are two findings while execution:

1. The suites are executed parallel and not the test case. i.e if there are two suite A and B , if A take 30 mins to complete and B takes 5 mins to complete, the total execution time is 30 mins, simply because each processes pick each suite and not test cases
   How can i run the test cases parallel and not the Suite parallel ?
2. It creates outputdir separately for each Test Suite `pabot_results\TestCases` that makes my rerunning of failed test cases difficult.
   How to get a single output.xml file all the suite execution ?

I use the below library

> robotframework-pabot==0.53 
>   robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First point: If you read [the GitHub readme page](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/blob/master/README.md), in the "Things you should know", it states:

> Pabot will split test execution from suite files and not from individual test level.

So there is nothing to do on test level, except if you help develop the tool so it becomes possible to launch testcases in parallel.

Second point: Use [rebot](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#rebot). You can merge multiple test execution reports by using the command:

```
rebot --merge output1.xml output2.xml
```

This will generate only html report. To obtain a merged output.xml file, just add an `-o output.xml` in the arguments, like this:

```
rebot -o output.xml --merge output1.xml output2.xml
```

Answer (score 6):

Now (after version 0.57) you can do this with

```
pabot --testlevelsplit [path to tests]
```

official link for more info https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot